# Programmatically get IP address of vm in Vagrant

Tags: python, vagrant

I'm trying to create a rest api which can launch, provision and destroy vagrant boxes.
So far I've managed to do most of the easy tasks such as provisioning, parsing logs to determine if provisioning was successfull, starting, stopping, destroying vms and parsing logs to find when a port was conflicting and has been remapped.

However, I can't figure out how to get around finding the new ip the box received from the router's DHCP.
I could run

```
vagrant ssh -c ifconfig
```

and try to parse the ip address but if i don't know the interface name it won't work.

Is there a way to have vagrant report what is it's local ip? alternatively is there a way to find this ip otherwise?

I'm using [python-vagrant](https://github.com/todddeluca/python-vagrant) to interface python with vagrant but at this point even executing shell commands through python would be acceptable.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You can tell the Vagrant to use a specific IP instead on getting a random one by adding

```html
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: '192.168.x.x'
end
```

You should already have the Vagrant.configure section and this will provision the box using the specific IP you define.

Comment: If this script that you are building suppose to dynamically generate VM boxes for different user; this approach wouldn't work unfortunately

Comment: thanks for the answer, you're right but then I need to manage all the ip addresses and also reserve an ip range on the DHCP. Also VMS with more than one interfaces need special treatment. 

After some research I think the best solution is to go with something like openstack or foreman. No reason reinventing the wheel

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.